# Is it possible to short hand code the singleton pattern?

Tags: c#-4.0

I was not sure how to properly title this question. Right now if you want to use a singleton pattern you would write a basic property called "Instance" that you could get off of a static reference like in the following example: `Factory.Instance.SomeMethod();`.

Is it possible in C# 4.5 to short hand the static call `Factory` to return a singleton instance so that when I do the call `Factory.SomeMethod();` , `SomeMethod()` is NOT a static method but a instance method from the instance returned by using the static type reference of `Factory`?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see how that would be possible. You still need a static field somewhere to refer to the instance. Best you could do is a static proxy method for each of the instance methods, I suppose.

Comment: yeah, you can't call a method as a static but have it run on an instance...  Why would you want this feature?

Comment: I was mostly curious to see what I can and can not do in the latest version of C#. The more things I know exist, the better I can be about coming at a problem in the future. Mind you this is a rather odd and specific situation.